# How can I load a script for just one component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this generated code for insert Privacy Policy to Website, but if I set this script in index.html I have this block on all pages, but I need only one page (one component).

```
<div id="__enzuzo-root"></div>
<script id="__enzuzo-root-script" src="..."></script>
```

Also, I have issue with inserting block to <div id="__enzuzo-root"...
I added useEffect for inserting script tag after render but it does not work

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const TermsOfService = _ => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://app.enzuzo.com/__en...";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, [])

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id="__enzuzo-root"></div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default TermsOfService;
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used iframe and everything worked

```
<iframe srcDoc={`<div id="__enzuzo-root-tos"></div><script src="..." type="text/javascript"></script>`} />
```

Comment: This aligns with what I said below, the iframe has a new context so it will call the onload event inside the iframe. Could be worth giving my edited answer a go.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly try `useLayoutEffect` which runs after the DOM has actually been rendered.

Secondly your div ID doesn't match the snippet.

You might also detect when script it loaded and trigger a page load event as the lib might be listening to it.

```
const TermsOfService = _ => {
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://app.enzuzo.com/__en...";
        script.async = true;
        script.onload = () => {
           dispatchEvent(new Event('load'))
           dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMContentLoaded'))
        }
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, [])

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id="__enzuzo-root"></div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default TermsOfService;
```

Comment: this does not solve my problem, the script is added successfully but it is not executed

Comment: Have you checked console for any errors?

Comment: I don't have any errors in the console

Comment: Sadly, its quite possible, even likely that the third party snippet may be hooking into window events to decide when to load the content. For example, `onload`. Since your page is written by react after these events, that would cause what you are seeing.

Comment: A workaround might be available in the docs of this thing. Sometimes libs like this expose  functions on `window` to be able to call into it programmatically at a time of your choosing, or force it to reload.

Comment: If they dont have an option for it you could try waiting for the script to load and then programmatically trigger a load event. I will edit my answer with this idea shortly

Comment: Ive gone ahead and edited it. Is a long shot.

Answer (score -1):

In order to add any script to the react component you have to use some packages like React Helmet.Please visit here and follow the instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet

Comment: What he did is fine though, react helmet does the exact same sort of thing under the hood.